# Spotify - "gid" of Tracks

Tags: spotify

I see there is a *`gid`* for each track on Spotify.
As you see in the [**image**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0ngxDyeMR-yQxVvLYJTSeR4rfwPr08O/view?usp=drivesdk), `B` is the track ID but I don't understand `A`.
Please check the response of the request shown in the previous image [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I38pq7-uYyHKBgB7SZz-2qECSV91eP91/view?usp=drivesdk).

Do you know what this gid is and how we can retrieve it?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**:
As an example, Spotify calls an API as `https://spclient.wg.spotify.com/metadata/4/track/1e763423ad0e4862b20f9dbfdadc2cb7` for the track https://open.spotify.com/track/0VtMV3IYHAu7fyZmqnGE99. as you see the the id at the end of the API URL is `1e763423ad0e4862b20f9dbfdadc2cb7` which is different from the track id (`0VtMV3IYHAu7fyZmqnGE99`). The response of the API is `{"gid": "1e763423ad0e4862b20f9dbfdadc2cb7","name": "Oh Yeah","album": {"gid": "b6a45388cac54953b3fe0f8e0ab7c729","name": "Oh Glory","artist": [{"gid": "e8dba066dc3644b1b69510eb3cdd8a42","name": "Aime Simone"}],"label": "No Start No End","date": {"year": 2023,"month": 5,"day": 5},"cover_group": {"image": [{"file_id": "ab67616d00001e026cddc8afe19c5950b5f6f5b6","size": "DEFAULT","width": 300,"height": 300},{"file_id": "ab67616d000048516cddc8afe19c5950b5f6f5b6","size": "SMALL","width": 64,"height": 64},{"file_id": "ab67616d0000b2736cddc8afe19c5950b5f6f5b6","size": "LARGE","width": 640,"height": 640}]},"licensor": {"uuid": "1b3fb428ae7b41aa97c9b46c5b962d57"},"prerelease_config": {"earliest_reveal_date": {"year": 2023,"month": 5,"day": 4,"hour": 11},"earliest_coverart_reveal_date": {"year": 2023,"month": 5,"day": 4,"hour": 11}}},"artist": [{"gid": "e8dba066dc3644b1b69510eb3cdd8a42","name": "Aime Simone"}],"number": 10,"disc_number": 1,"duration": 122293,"popularity": 41,"external_id": [{"type": "isrc","id": "FR9W12241433"}],"file": [{"file_id": "a0ee4ae82c323cf5e45361670079e6a68f391b2f","format": "OGG_VORBIS_320"},{"file_id": "0d508123a2197901602399756f091ba8225ff781","format": "OGG_VORBIS_160"},{"file_id": "698098f862955a08c9204e9cd723de32ad4e48e2","format": "OGG_VORBIS_96"},{"file_id": "0833e88386b0320aabcc56ab893c1ae157a5fffc","format": "MP4_256_DUAL"},{"file_id": "999bff5d82f078c4d6c12a88ee7401e6cf36c048","format": "MP4_256"},{"file_id": "cca2b23924cc42ed2b8f1efc1c95766c5f26a7c8","format": "MP4_128"},{"file_id": "f80419a11fa42bb9054ef4975bdba2a7c2226077","format": "MP4_128_DUAL"},{"file_id": "41af902734adfc123dba2bb91fa1138c7632af6c","format": "AAC_24"}],"preview": [{"file_id": "b2f08b0f87cdef5489d51588dc61e5b6fd7e5ca2","format": "MP3_96"}],"earliest_live_timestamp": 1683198000,"has_lyrics": true,"licensor": {"uuid": "1b3fb428ae7b41aa97c9b46c5b962d57"},"language_of_performance": ["en"],"original_audio": {"uuid": "87a724f901a34555a86efdc16b65ee9b"},"original_title": "Oh Yeah","artist_with_role": [{"artist_gid": "e8dba066dc3644b1b69510eb3cdd8a42","artist_name": "Aime Simone","role": "ARTIST_ROLE_MAIN_ARTIST"}],"canonical_uri": "spotify:track:0VtMV3IYHAu7fyZmqnGE99","prerelease_config": {"earliest_reveal_date": {"year": 2023,"month": 5,"day": 4,"hour": 11}}}`.

Comment: can you explain more? the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gid` probably means something like `Global ID` or something of that sort. I've done some research ([python codebase](https://github.com/Hexxeh/spotify-websocket-api/blob/master/spotify_web/spotify.py), [JS codebase](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-spotify-web/build/apidoc.html)) and found that this `gid` is some hexadecimal number which needs to be converted to a base62 number to get the actual ID.

In both codebases the functions used to convert the `gid` to the ID and then to an URI are called `gid2id` and `id2uri`.
I've tried both but they either didn't work quite well as expected, meaning they didn't give the desired result or referenced functions that weren't in the codebase, so I've decided to throw together my own quick converter in python:

```
def gid_to_base62(gid):
base62_charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
decimal_number = int(gid, 16)
base62_id = ''

while decimal_number > 0:
    remainder = decimal_number % 62
    base62_id = base62_charset[remainder] + base62_id
    decimal_number = decimal_number // 62

return base62_id

gid = '1e763423ad0e4862b20f9dbfdadc2cb7'
base62_id = gid_to_base62(gid)
print(base62_id) # -> 0VtMV3IYHAu7fyZmqnGE99
```

Now I have only tested this on 2 example gid's so use this converter with caution.

Comment: can we convert trackId back to gid?